# Processing time inserted by now() function php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in processing and comparing time of each row in my tables. I want to get the result from database which are just created in the last seven days but the problem is the data saved in the database are saved using now() format and are like this :1497867945 ; I really don't know how to deal with it. well I received this database as it is and should give back the PHP codes based on the database. 
I would appreciate your help.
The array used to save data in database including the time is as follow :

```
     $update=array(
                'title'=>$this->input->post('post_name'),
                'text'=>$this->input->post('post_body'),
                'img'=>$image,
                'time'=>now(),
                'cat_id'=>$this->input->post('post_cat')
            );
```

Comment: It's UNIX time. Use date() to convert it.

Comment: are you using any framework ?

Comment: `echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$update['time']);`   https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: yes im using codeigniter framework

Comment: i shouldnt change the table structure and the way data are stored in each column .thats the problem

Comment: you can change this back into a readable timestamp in MySQL: select from_unixtime(time); or in php : date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result['time']);

Comment: It seems like the way you are passing NOW() is incorrect. Pass it as below if you want to use mysql NOW()    'time'=>'NOW()',

Comment: you should put now() in singleQuotes: 'now()', but it will still be a unix_timestamp in your DB